# Intuition behind non-local stress tensor

Tags: continuum-mechanics, stress-strain, non-locality, fractals

Starting from the following Reisz Fractional Integro-differential formula (see for example [https://www.amazon.com/Fractional-Integrals-Derivatives-Theory-Applications/dp/2881248640](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/2881248640), chapter 25)

$$
I^{\alpha} \varepsilon(\mathbf{x}) \propto \int_{R^d} \frac{\varepsilon(\mathbf{y}) d\mathbf{y}}{|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}|^{d-\alpha}}
$$

where the proportionality constant is unimportant now. My questions are:

1) Is the limit $ \alpha \rightarrow 0 $, i.e. the functional
$$
I^{0} [\#](\mathbf{x}) \propto \int_{R^d} \frac{ [\#] (\mathbf{y}) d\mathbf{y}}{|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}|^{d}}
$$ 
some representation of delta distribution (with a proper proportionality constant)?

2) Consider the case where $ \varepsilon(\mathbf{x}) $ is the stress tensor. The above formula should describe the non-local stress in a continuum medium, but how should I qualitatively imagine the above formula? Can someone give me examples for various values of $ \alpha $? Should I think of $ \alpha $ as some parameter that describes the deviation from the locally "delta distributed" stress?

Comment: It seems you're studying a particularly specialized mathematics, so maybe the questions and symbols are above my head, but, from a naïve first glance, have you thought of the following, which springs to the unspecialist mind (apologies if there's more to this than I know): Question 1:  No. Work out $\int_{-\infty}^\infty  \frac{1}{y}\,\frac{y}{1+y^2} \mathrm{d} y$ and compare with $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\,\delta(y)\, \frac{y}{1+y^2} \,\mathrm{d} y$. Question 2: clearly no, given answer to question 1.

Comment: Actually the reality is that tensors (local linear functions on the tangent space) are much more of an approximation than commonly assumed, *e.g.* in  electromagnetic materials. It's simply that tensors approximate well over length scales much larger than the wavelength and most often one isn't interested in scales that are much finer than that.